# How use a where function with just a part of json value?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

How are you doing?

I'm currently using PostgreSQL and want to create a `'where'` with just a specif date but the value returns me a kind of timestamp.
Example of the json:

What the json looks like:

```
{"key1": {"key2": "2023-02-13T13:28:49.087000Z"}}
```

What I'm doing:

```
select *
from table
where json(column) -> 'key1' ->> 'key2' = '2023-02-14'
```

Ps: the json column 'details' is in text format so I converted i into json

**I want to get the results where the key2 value is '2023-02-14'.**

Comment: `details` should be defined with the data type `jsonb` (or at least `json`)  so that you can get rid of the constant casting if you want to do anything useful with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LIKE operator:

```
select *
from the_table
where details::json -> 'key1' ->> 'key2' like '2023-02-14%'
```

Or a bit shorter:

```
select *
from the_table
where details::json #>> '{key1,key2}' like '2023-02-14%'
```

Comment: I followed your response but sqlpad returs me the following message: "invalid input syntax for type json"

Comment: Then apparently your column doesn't contain valid JSON - another good reason why that should have been defined as `jsonb` (or at least `json`)  right from the start: then it's impossible to store invalid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 steps required to what you you want.

Step 1. Cast string column to json using PostgreSQL [json operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html) and fetch the needed column.

```
col_a::json->'key1'->>'key2'
```

Step 2: use PostgreSQL [substring()](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-string-functions/postgresql-substring/) function to fetch the date part of the string, full query example as below:

```
select *
from table
where substring(col_a::json->'key1'->>'key2',1,10) = '2023-02-14'
```

Comment: I followed your response but sqlpad returs me the following message: "invalid input syntax for type json"

Comment: try cast(col_a as json) syntax, if it still doesn't work the json in some rows in your table are invalid.